# Basic authentication in web api

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, asp.net-web-api

I started working on Web Api and just want to create a simple basic authentication. I want to know how to do that?

I tried with the given MSDN link but no step wise tutorial is given on MSDN.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Comment: Related question: [ASP.net Web API RESTful web service + Basic authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17121964/145173)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The link you gave provides much of the detail you need, I hope this fills in the blanks.

**Note:** If using Web.API 2, Microsoft are suggesting a different approach using [authentication filters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters).

#### Set up https on your server

This is quite important if you need real security otherwise passwords can be gleaned by snooping parties. How you do this depends a entirely on your setup, which you don't detail, but if you're working on an Azure WebRole there's a pretty good [step-by-step guide to setting up SSL](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/) from Microsoft.

This isn’t required for the next steps, but should be done before you release your code. I mention it first because this part usually involves getting other people involved (sysadmin for server config, finance to purchase the certificate, etc) and it’s good to give them lots of warning.

#### Write (or steal) a custom IHttpModule to do your authentication

This is the big block of C# code [in your link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) - it parses the values sent by the browser and sets HttpContext.Current.User to the authenticated user. Just copy and paste the meat into a class in your own application and we’ll come back to it later. You’ll need the following using statements in your code.

```
using System; using System.Net.Http.Headers; using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text; using System.Threading; using System.Web;
```

#### Associate that module with your application

Add a new module to your web.config file (note system.webServer probably already exists)

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="BasicAuth" type="Full.ClassName.Path.BasicAuth, Assembly.Name"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

#### Restrict access to the relevant parts of your site

You can block specific actions by adding the [Authorize] attribute before the action definition. Block a whole controller by adding it before your controller class.

```
[Authorize] // Restricts access to whole controller    
public class StockController : ApiController {
    [Authorize] // Restricts access to this action - not necessary if whole controller restricted.
    public IEnumerable<StockLevel> Get() {
```

Or in your App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs file you can add `config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());` and it will lock everything down.

Something to watch out for - there’s also a `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` so if you have that namespace included you can get confusing results.

At this point you can try it out - user: "user", pass: "password".

#### Customize your user validation

Go back to the class we stole from the link and you'll see the following block of code:

```
// TODO: Here is where you would validate the username and password.
private static bool CheckPassword(string username, string password)
```

Alter this to return true if the username and password are valid. If you're rolling your own you may want to investigate [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (do you trust the implementation you downloaded off the net?), [PBKDF2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) or the [Crypto class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538437(v=vs.111).aspx) (simple but not terribly secure) but there's probably something better from Microsoft as there are lot of concerns around storing passwords properly.

Comment: Such a great write up! One of the better response I've seen, really helped me learn more about BasicAuth and how to get it setup the way I needed. Thanks!

Comment: What's not terribly secure with the Crypto class? It looks like it's using PBKDF2 which is what you want: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs

Comment: The Crypto class is only doing 1000 iterations, which was the recommended minimum number in the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt), published in 2000 and AFAIK it doesn't let you change that value (the code you reference has it as a const). Reading around, you'll find recommendations to double that every year since 2000 - but it really should be tuned to your deployment hardware as it's a trade-off between ease-of-hack and impact-to-users. See this question for more details: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a few lines of code to the MSDN example to get it to work. Specifically, in OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(), I set the response status code to 401 if the user could not be validated:

```
private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
            bool validated = false;
            if (authHeader != null)
            {
                var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

                // RFC 2617 sec 1.2, "scheme" name is case-insensitive
                if (authHeaderVal.Scheme.Equals("basic",
                                                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                    authHeaderVal.Parameter != null)
                {
                    validated = AuthenticateUser(authHeaderVal.Parameter);
                }
            }

            if (!validated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        }
```

Once I did that, it worked fine. There's probably better ways to structure the logic, but this is about the smallest change from the example that does the job.

Comment: With your modification, every request is being authenticated even those that may not have to. When authHeader is null, validate will stay false, and you will return 401. Well, the pages/resources that don't need authentication (i.e. controllers/actions decorated with [AllowAnonymous]) *will be missing* authHeader...Right? Or maybe I need more coffee :)

Comment: You're probably right. I'm still learning this stuff. I have since changed my implementation from an HttpModule to an HttpHandler, but your comment still applies - if I have a page with [AllowAnonymous], it's still trying to authenticate. If you know a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: the code in the link that OP posted works without any modification.You don't need `if (!validated) {...}` block - the `OnApplicationEndRequest()` method, I believe, "takes care" of this.

Answer (score 1):

To selectively enable basic authentication on a per-controller or per-method basis, you can derive from `AuthorizeAttribute` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17121964/145173).