# C# Web API - Security for some of the GET requests

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, get, authorization

On an existing host I've added Web API Models & Controllers. I've added the following four:

- Products
- Orders
- Categories
- Users

When someone accesses the `localhost:port\api\products`, it returns all the products in JSON format.

The Create, Update and Delete statements are completely disabled, so we are only able to use GET-requests on the API (so either `\api\products` for a list of all products or `api\products\#` for a single products with id #).

Because the other CRUD's aren't used, there isn't a lot of security that should be added to the Web API, except for one thing: **The Users**

These will also return emails and such, which would be better to keep private and unreadable without the proper authorization (without entire log-in pages, but a way to authenticate yourself when accessing the Web API in for example Android HttpGetRequests).

So, the question: **How should I add authorization for only the UsersController accessed by the Web API.**

And, how can I encrypt the JSON in C# and decrypt it in Android again. If this second part is too big to answer I'll make a new question later on, my main focus is the low-end [<- without log-in pages, so built in into the GET-request] authorization of the Web API's GET-request for Users.

---

Edit 1: I did found [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) where a new project is made with Authorization Changed to Individual Users. I also see that the user is registered and then logged in with POST and GET requests.

The following questions came into mind when reading through this link:

- How to change the Web API's Authorization to Individual Users on an existing project?
- Our authorization is done through OAuth (mainly Google-account) with our work e-mail address. I guess it's not possible / easy to authorize in the same way as in the link with a Google-account on Web API GET-requests.

---

Edit 2: After using the [first link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) provided by Vladimir Gondarev I've added the `[Authorize]` to both the Get methods in the UsersController. In my project everything else was already used before, like a class that uses the AuthorizeAttribute, so just adding the `[Authorize]` was already enough for the first step. Now in the browser I get an unauthorized (JSON) back when I'm not logged in, which is good.

The next step would be to add the OAuth-authorization to the Android app, but that is an entire new problem / question that I will look into first before asking a new stackoverflow-question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be "Basic Authentification". In order to to implement it you have to derive from AuthorizeAttribute and then apply it to a method or a controller.
Here you find further info:

What is basic Authentification:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Implementation:

[ASP.net Web API RESTful web service + Basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121964/asp-net-web-api-restful-web-service-basic-authentication)

You don't have to encrypt anything as long as you use HTTPS transport.

Comment: Thanks for the first link, after I added `[Authorize]` to the Get-methods of the UsersController it's already enough, since everything else was already present in the project. And since I already added OAuth-authorization to the Android app, I can now focus on the Android app and commit the Web API changes to the online host.