# C# Web Api with OAuth and Basic authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, basic-authentication

I have an Asp.net web api, which is configured with OAuth. Now I have new client who cannot use Oauth but wants to use Basic Authentication with the same endpoint url.

Haven't found any ways to do this yet. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.net Web API RESTful web service + Basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121964/asp-net-web-api-restful-web-service-basic-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not duplicate. Checked the link. Here the question is how to use OAuth/Basic authentication based on request.

Comment: I don't think the 2 can be integrated.

The only way I can think of that might work would be to have a web page the requires basic authentication, which can then get a bearer token and use the bearer token to authenticate with the main app.

Comment: @MoD Any sample code that can help

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if ((Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name?.Length ?? 0) <= 0)
        {
            AuthenticationHeaderValue auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            if (string.Compare(auth.Scheme, "Basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                string credentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Parameter));
                int separatorIndex = credentials.IndexOf(':');
                if (separatorIndex >= 0)
                {
                    string userName = credentials.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
                    string password = credentials.Substring(separatorIndex + 1);
                    var userManager = new MembershipUserManager();
                    var user = userManager.FindAsync(userName, password).Result;
                    if (user != null)
                        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName, "Basic"), System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(userName));
                }
            }
        }
        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Use this code once you have set up the token auth (Oauth) and this would work for both: This attribute should be used everywhere (ditch the Authorize) [contains roles] and would verify the Basic auth, whereas the base.IsAuthorized(actionContext); would verify the token approach (Oauth).

MembershipUserManager is a custom class I've created to make this work with Membership, I'm guessing you'd use Identity User Manager.

Comment: Thanks @Riste Golaboski. I will try this and update here.